# Oracle Client components to install for using Oracle in .NET application

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, oracleclient

I have to connect an Orcle DB (virtual machine) from my .NET application. After reading some tutorials and docs I recognized that there are several components which could/should be installed:
 - Oracle Client (not Oracle Instant client since it doesn't have tnsping)
 - ODP.NET 2.0
 - ODP.NET 4.0
 - Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (incl. Oracle Data Access Components)

My suggestion was just to install the Oracle Client 11g (ca. 601 MB). Then I fogured out that it doesn't include ODP.NET 4.0.

Only installing Oracle Data Access Components delivers ODP.NET 2.0 and 4.0 bit it uses the instant client that doesn't include the tnsping tool. I need the tool to check the conenctin to the DB in the virtual machine.

Installing both packages after another disables the previous configuration so after it nothing works properly.

Can you tell me what exactly I have to install and in which order? As I said, I need Oracle connecntion, tnsping and some possibility to open connection from Visual Studio to inspect the DB data.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is make sure you get the latest Visual Studio tools package called "ODAC [version] with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio". Currently, it's located at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html but that may change years from now.

Then I'd install ALL of the components from your newly downloaded installer. You really don't need to worry about the disk space on your average developer's desktop, as it's only around a 230 MB download as of today. (Version 11.2.0.2.1 is current at the time of this writing.)

Comment: But includes only the Instant Client which doesn't have tnsping.

Comment: Indeed the best way is to install only the ODAC with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio. You will not have tnsping but you'll get working connectin from Visual Studio.To get tnsping on your Instant Client following the instructions here: http://jasonvogel.blogspot.com/2007/10/oracle-instantclient-tnsping-and-plsql.html

Comment: Yikes, that is a Frankenstein's Monster of a setup, but it looks like it would work!